# Human Position Tracking

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, tracking

I need to write a software project for Human Location Tracking in a room, something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4R5LlpGUpqY

Requirement is the ability to enable tracking of the phone (application in android) and 2D tracking result in this application.

So I use application that communicates with eg raspberry (arduino?) Enables tracing and sends data to phone? This is good idea?

I started thinking about the hardware that I should use, what would be the best idea?
Radar, motion sensor, wifi? (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuQsGNq_6as)? How many sensor - radar etc ?

I do not know where I should start...

Comment: did my answer helpfull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However your question appears to be off topic but for starting point I suggest you take a look at [this tag in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indoor-positioning-system) which is about indoor positioning. and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098122/how-to-improve-accuracy-of-indoor-positioning) and also see [This Project](https://github.com/mmusaab/indoor-position-tracker) that might help you more.

Other links that might help:

1- [10-things-you-need-to-know-about-indoor-positioning](http://www.directionsmag.com/articles/10-things-you-need-to-know-about-indoor-positioning/324602)

2- [Indoor Wireless Navigation](http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring11/group02/index.html)